# Google Play web scraping: How to identify response to app reviews in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-play, app-store, rstudio

I am doing web scraping in R of the reviews of a Google Play application, but I cannot identify the lack of response to the reviews.

I explain. I intend to set up a database with two columns. One with the text of the review and another column with the app's response to that review. In this last column, it will have empty values when there is no response. However, I only get the answers and I cannot identify the absence of an answer. How can this be done?

**INPUT**

[image]

**OUPUT** ***What I want to be returned***

[image]

*How I can get this? Identify the absence of response*

**FULL CODE**

```
#Loading the rvest package
library(rvest)
library(magrittr) # for the '%>%' pipe symbols
library(RSelenium) # to get the loaded html of 


url <- 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gospace.parenteral&showAllReviews=true'

# starting local RSelenium (this is the only way to start RSelenium that is working for me atm)
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

# go to website
remDr$navigate(url)


# get page source and save it as an html object with rvest
html_obj <- remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()

#1 column
reviews <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".UD7Dzf") %>% html_text()

#2 column
reply <- html_obj %>% html_nodes('.LVQB0b') %>% html_text()


# create the df with all the info
review_data <- data.frame(reviews = reviews, reply = reply, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your page, but the way to do this is to get the `html_nodes` of the `div` sections containing both the reviews and replies (which will probably contain the name of the reviewer as well), and then to `purrr::map` through this list of nodes extracting the `html_node() %>% html_text` for the review nodes and reply nodes separately. These will be the same length, and any non-existent ones will come out as `NA`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But I don't understand very well what you mean. Could you type the command? From this or any other google play app

Comment: Get the review boxes with something like `reviewboxes <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".zc7KVe")` and then `reviews <- map_chr(reviewboxes, ~html_node(., ".UD7Dzf") %>% html_text())` and similarly for `reply`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Thanks to your contribution I have achieved it this way. First this: `reviewboxes <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".d15Mdf")` and then this:`reply <- map_chr(reviewboxes, ~html_node(., ".QoPmEb") %>% html_text())`